# How to register device token in Urban Airship for Push Notification?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am using Urban airship for sending push notification, and i successfully achieved this. Now i am stuck an issue that before registering device token into urban airship i couldn't able to send broadcast, if i am wrong on this then how can i can send notifications into many devices in which my app is installed without registering their device tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey You have to register your app as `In production, connecting to real push servers.` and check out this link http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/push/index.html
 it may be helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

The broadcast should work in development mode as well.

When you login to "go" do you see your "Device Tokens" listed under your app? The other thing that could be a problem is if you have recently switch your app from development to production - if you try and send device tokens to APNS that are not mis-matched (production device tokens sent to sandbox vice-versa) you'll run in to this issue and likely see some sporadic results.

If you are in dev mode, you could simply delete the existing device tokens then get a few re-registered, then retry a broadcast.